# SQL Query to add Previous Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write stored procedure (or SQL Query) in SQL server where in I will have 2 columns namely Month and count. Count value represents number of documents which is already present in the same table where in these 2 columns present.
In month column, there will be 12 months and in count column , I want , addition of number of documents in that month and number of documents till previous month.For e.g.In january I have 20 documents and in Feb there are 10 documents then this Stored Procedure will return me 20+10=30 documents for February Month and likewise.How can I achieve this.

Comment: Start by trying something.

Comment: Provide an initial script and the desired output, please.

Comment: can you provide sample data table with values?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the partial information you have provided, following pseudo code should help:

```
create table t1 ( month int, [countdocs] int)
insert into t1 values (1,20),(2,10)

SELECT Cur.month, isnull(Cur.countdocs,0) + isnull(Prv.countdocs,0) AS countdocs
FROM t1 AS Cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 AS Prv
ON Cur.month = Prv.month + 1;
```

Comment: i think he needs only one row returned, even am scratching my head after your progress ..:)
Its rather easy sum(docs) where month <= @month

Comment: I want 12 rows in output.(1 row per month and corresponding count).I thought of using Lead ,Lag clause in SQL Query but not sure if it will be able to run successfully on every version of SQL server like 2012,2008,2005,2000 etc. since I want to use it for different applications having different SQL versions as backend.

Comment: what's the issue you are facing with suggested query? What's not working here?

Answer (score 0):

Look up windowing functions in SQL server. You appear to want a running total and there are techniques to get those from windowing fn.